# Duration on Divine Domain Shadow: Channel Divinity: Favor of Darkness

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric, homebrew, divine, domains

This sort of has 2 questions... Under the description I see no duration anywhere in either the standard players handbook for Channel Divinity and also in the Volume of Forgotten Lore book for this ability as well.

> Starting at 2nd level, by presenting your holy symbol and spending a
>   use of Channel Divinity, you can flood a 30-foot radius centered on
>   you with magical shadows. All sources of light within the radius,
>   magical or otherwise, are extinguished, and light coming from sources
>   beyond that radius is dimmed: bright light becomes dim, and dim light
>   becomes darkness. You and any creatures of your choice within the
>   area, however, can see in this area as if the lighting had not
>   changed.
>   You can concentrate on this effect as though it were a spell. Each
>   round you concentrate, you can also spend a bonus action to expand the
>   area of reduced light by an additional 15 feet. Once you cease
>   concentrating, the area of mystical shadow lingers until the end of
>   your next turn.

Can I theoretically channel this forever?  If so, can I continue to channel it until it covers basically a whole town given enough time?  So doing so at night would basically wrap the entire town in pure darkness.

Comment: Volume of Forgotten Lore is not an official 5e content.  Can you provide a larger context for the feature from the homebrew content?

Comment: Is Volume of Forgotten Lore DM Guild material?  Some of the people who participate here may be familiar with it.

Comment: O i had no idea.  Our DM provided the content.  I'll add the full text for it.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I have no idea TBH.  Our DM provided the material.

Comment: By the reading of the feature, it seems like _any_ brightly-lit area outside that sphere becomes dim light! Including that town 5 miles away...

Comment: @daze413 I actually read it as the light sources that go into the area from an external location.  That means it doesn't darken the sun or other locations, but instead the sun doesn't make the area within the darkness spot bright and instead changes it to dim light.  Same with the moon from dim light to darkness only within the area of darkness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes!

Your bonus action is all that is required to do this. Depending on your table rules for going without sleep, this may be difficult to continue your concentration through the whole process.

As always, beware of possibly unbalanced 3rd party resources. If your table is okay with it, then by all means, go for it! Blanket that town in Darkness!

Comment: Ya, I'm assuming that at some point I'll probably pull this move out and surprise DM with it.  I just wanted to see if there was any simple reason I couldn't do it that I overlooked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***You CAN - depending.***

You can expand the radius of darkness so long as you *retain concentration* on the ability.

**Concentration**

Normal activity, such as moving and attacking, doesn’t
interfere with concentration. The following factors can
break concentration:

- Casting another spell that requires concentration. You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can’t concentrate on two spells at once.
- Taking damage. Whenever you take damage while you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration. The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take, whichever number is higher. If you take damage from multiple sources, such as an arrow and a dragon’s breath, you make a separate saving throw for each source of damage.
- Being incapacitated or killed. You lose concentration on a spell if you are incapacitated or if you die.

It should also be noted that, unless you are a certain race or possess the correct abilities, you must **Eat** and **Sleep** at certain intervals.

So long as you have the ability to stave off sleep, you can eat during a rest, meaning - ***YES, you can potentially focus on this spell forever and engulf the world in pure darkness.*** What this will do for you, I'm not sure, as you'd always have to remain *concentrated* on the ability, meaning you wouldn't be having much fun once global darkness has been achieved. Maybe brainwash someone else to do it for you, or even a clone.

Also, given that an average town may be about a square mile, and the darkness grows 15ft per round, and one round is considered 6 seconds being as you are the only person taking turns, I'd say that it would take you about 40 minutes to engulf the entire town. By those same measurements, it would take you 28.5 weeks or 200 days to engulf the entire world. Good luck in your shadow snow globe!

Comment: Ya I'm excited to surprise my dm with this move!